# ColdFusion 10 Administrator - Secure DNS

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have a webserver connected to an old database.  The old database server is end of life.  When we set that up we did not need a secure connection.  Now we have a new database on a new database server.  Our IT department is requiring this to be a secure connection (even though it's an intranet).

Using ColdFusion Administrator I tried simply editing the URL of the server, but I get this error:

> Connection verification failed for data source: xxxxxxxx
>   java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer
>   JDBC Driver]The SQL Server login requires an SSL connection. The root
>   cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]The SQL Server login requires an
>   SSL connection.

That's when I heard from my IT people that it needs to be a secure connection.

I have no idea how to do that, and Google didn't offer me any help, probably because I don't know what to search for.

Could one of you wonderful people please offer a suggestion on how to create a secure connection from ColdFusion Administrator 10 to MS SQL 2008?

Thank you

Comment: My suggestion is to seek assistance from the IT people who are setting this requirement.

Comment: I have not done it recently, but also check the docs on [Enabling SSL Connections](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/data-source-management-for-coldfusion.html#DataSourceManagementforColdFusion-EnablingSSLConnection)